# How to check if HTML5 audio has reached different errors

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Specifically, if one of the 206 requests for audio fails and buffering stops, is there a way to detect that state? Or should I have to check if buffering stopped by comparing the buffered amounts against past amounts?

Also how can I check if the specified source fails, could you then point it to another source?

Comment: can you show the code you are using to load this files (3 or 4 of the 206)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**1. Specifically, if one of the requests for audio fails and buffering stops, is there a way to detect that state?**

Yes, there is few ways to do this! But if you want to catch the error type you can attach the error event listener to the sources:

```
$('audio').addEventListener('error', function failed(e) {
   // audio playback failed - show a message saying why
   // to get the source of the audio element use $(this).src
   switch (e.target.error.code) {
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
       alert('You aborted the video playback.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
       alert('A network error caused the audio download to fail.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
       alert('The audio playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
       alert('The video audio not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.');
       break;
     default:
       alert('An unknown error occurred.');
       break;
   }
 }, true);
```

**2. Could you then point it to another source?**

Inside the error handler function you can change the source using the `src` property of the audio element:

```
var audio = $(this);
audio.src = "new-audio-file.mp3";
audio.load();
```

Another option is to add multiple source to the same audio tag using this syntax:

```
<audio>
    <source id="audio_player_ogv" src="test.ogv" type="audio/ogg" />
    //In case that you can't load the ogv file it will try to load test.mp3
    <source id="audio_player_mp3" src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

**3. About manage multiple audio files**

I would suggest to use a plugin if you are thinking to manage 206 audio files. I have been using [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) for a while and it's very good!

Comment: ++ on SoundManager2, though due to the flash fallback it won't work with mobile...or at least I don't think so, will it?

Comment: @TomSarduy `$('audio').addEventListener` is that jQuery?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs: yes, that's jquery, but just to save some code ;)

Comment: On Chrome 57, for solution 1, I had to replace
`e.target.error.code`
by
`e.detail.target.error.code`

Answer (score 3):

There is a complete list of the events handled by media elements in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#media-elements

I would look specifically at the stalled, abort, progress events.

Since this element is relatively new implementations may vary greatly.  So I would test these events against the platforms you are targeting to see if they work as expected for your needs.  If not you may need to do something a bit more manual like polling the buffered state as you had mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can find your answer here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) at the end of page (Media Events block)

probably `onerror` or `onstalled` or `onreadystatechange`