# Detecting HTML5 audio element file not found error

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to make a the browser display an alert if an audio element src attribute points to a non existent file, however I do not get any response if I attach the the  "error" event.

Here's a fiddle with my problem and with what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2PW/7/

The HTML:

```
<p>Non existent audio files - should return an error
    <audio preload="auto">
        <source src="http://example.com/non-existant.wav" />
        <source src="http://example.com/non-existant.mp3" />
        <source src="http://example.com/non-existant.ogg" />
    </audio>
</p>
<p>Existing audio file - should just play
    <audio preload="auto">
        <source src="http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a" />
    </audio>
</p>
```

And the JS:

```
playerMarkup = "<a class=\"player\">Play</a>";
audioTags = $("audio");

audioTags.before(playerMarkup); //insert markup before each audio tag

$(".player").on("click", function () {
    currentAudio = $(this).next()[0];
    //I've tried catching the error like this - no effect
    alert("Trying to play file.");
    try {
        currentAudio.play();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error playing file!");
    }
});

//I've also tried just handling the event error - no effect
audioTags.on("error", function (e) {
    alert("Error playing file!");
    console.log("Error playing file!");
});
```

How can I detect an error of the file not being played (because of not being found) with JS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You actually need to bind to the source tag for listening to error event when willing to detect "file not found error". Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWzC2/5/).

HTML:

```
<p id="player1">Non existent audio files - click to play</p>

<audio preload="none" controls>
    <source id="wav" src="http://example.com/non-existant.wav" />
    <source id="mp3" src="http://example.com/non-existant.mp3" />
    <source id="ogg" src="http://example.com/non-existant.ogg" />
</audio>
```

Script:

```
$("#player1").on("click", function () {
    //I've tried catching the error like this - no effect
    alert("Trying to play file.");
    try {
        $('audio')[0].play();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error playing file!");
    }
});

$("audio").on("error", function (e) {
        alert("Error at audio tag level!");
    });

// try this then
$("#wav").on("error", function (e) {
        alert("Error with wav file!");
    });
$("#mp3").on("error", function (e) {
        alert("Error with mp3 file!");
    });
$("#ogg").on("error", function (e) {
        alert("Error with ogg file!");
    });
```

It is described in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Playing_Ogg_videos_using_a_Java_applet) - section error handling.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Brilliant, that's it - thanks for the link to the documentation as well, once you know it's the source element, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Any idea how to this in React component?

Comment: This worked great for me. However, is there a way to determine either the http status code returned from the call that caused the error, or what the error was?

Comment: @asubanovsky you'd need to add an `onError` callback on the source element. My react skills are rusty but I'm doing the equivalent in Vue

`<source onError={ /* handleErrorFunc */} src="url/soundfile.mp3" />`

Answer (score 7):

This should handle both cases (e.g. using `<audio>` with `<source>` tags or using `<audio src="">`).
See [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X537Q/).

```js
function handleSourceError(e) { alert('Error loading: '+e.target.src) }
function handleMediaError(e) {
    switch (e.target.error.code) {
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
            alert('You aborted the media playback.'); break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
            alert('A network error caused the media download to fail.'); break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
            alert('The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.'); break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            alert('The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.'); break;
        default:
            alert('An unknown media error occurred.');
    }
}

var toArray = Array.prototype.slice;
toArray.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')).forEach(function(audio){
    audio.addEventListener('error', handleMediaError);
    toArray.apply(audio.getElementsByTagName('source')).forEach(function(source){
        source.addEventListener('error', handleSourceError);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to point out, handleSourceError does not trigger when using audio tag without <source> ..

Comment: @rasjani that's what the handleMediaError is for. Using that snippet of code will handle both cases.

Comment: it was a literal comment for people who might be reading this  and not realizing what is the difference between two approaches.

Comment: @rasjani ahh, my mistake. Carry on, sir!

Answer (score 3):

Getting audio errors

```
$('audio').addEventListener('error', function failed(e) {
   // audio playback failed - show a message saying why
   // to get the source of the audio element use $(this).src
   switch (e.target.error.code) {
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
       alert('You aborted the video playback.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
       alert('A network error caused the audio download to fail.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
       alert('The audio playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.');
       break;
     case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
       alert('The video audio not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.');
       break;
     default:
       alert('An unknown error occurred.');
       break;
   }
 }, true);
```

Quoted from [How to check if HTML5 audio has reached different errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614803/how-to-check-if-html5-audio-has-reached-different-errors)

Comment: I forgot to say - I tried that solution before writing the question, and it does not seem to work for the scenario of file not found, which is none of MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED, MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK, MEDIA_ERR_DECODE, MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED. Does it work for you? I cannot get my code to even fire the alert from the error event handler, not to mention running through a switch block.