# If the file host doesn't work, how would I change the HTML so that the source is local?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a audio tag in a HTML file

```
<audio id="something">
    <source src="https://instaud.io/_/1tw6.mp3">
</audio>
```

but say that the web host is down, how would I change it so that it access the local file instead?

let's say that this html file is in a folder and so is the audio file, but I'll only move the audio file into the folder if the web host doesn't work.

What would I do here because I have literally no idea.

Comment: What do you mean by " I'll only move the audio file into the folder if the web host doesn't work". Did you mean the source of audio in HTML?

Comment: Use <source src="C:path_to_yourfile" />

Comment: I would assume the simplest solution is just add another source - have you read, say, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) docs for audio?

Comment: I am trying to make the final project as small as possible, and it will be in a folder, I'll include a folder with audio files as a google drive link that you can download if the web host doesn't work, hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: @TiesonT. but wouldn't there be an error if one of the files doesn't exist?

Comment: I don't think the spec explicitly calls out the expected behavior if a resource can't be loaded - I would expect the browser to try loading the next source rather than generating an error. I would read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content#Playing_Ogg_videos_using_a_Java_applet) or review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231404/detecting-html5-audio-element-file-not-found-error - I haven't had to deal with audio recently, so I can't actually answer your question with any confidence.