# Check for available listener slots on SHOUTcast server with PHP and/or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, shoutcast

We have a radio station using SHOUTcast to broadcast with. Links on our website are currently pointed at playlist files. The site is non-responsive and very out-of-date so I'm re-building it and am putting an HTML 5/jQuery player on the pages. All works fine but I've noticed that the better quality 128k stream only has 25 available listener slots.  The second stream is 64k and has 100.  Obviously, I would rather use the 128k where possible but looking at the listener peaks of both, it adds to 31 (more than 25) so this means potentially we will have all 25 slots used up and someone else may come to the site and the player probably won't play for them.

In this case I would like to just play the 64k stream instead. No matter how likely/unlikely this event may be, I still think I need to check if any slots are available on the 128k stream and push the 64k stream to the player if the 128k stream is full.

Using PHP and/or jQuery.  How can i check the SHOUTcast server available listener slot counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were to check for available slots, there is no guarantee that someone won't begin streaming at the same time, causing an error.

The proper way to handle the situation is to attempt a connection to your 128k stream, and fall back to the 64k stream if there is an error.  If you are using the HTML5 audio methods, there are [several errors you can handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14489392/362536).

Comment: ok sweet iu never really thoughjt of checking for errors on this but that's much slicker and works for other problems i hadn't thought of. also it stops me trying to access stuff on the shoutcast end that i'm very much pulling my hair out over. thanks very much Brad.