# Catching HTML5 media network error javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway I can catch a network error in case I try to create a `new Audio()` object and the src URL is not resolved? try/catch doesn't work here apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You have docs here: [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Playing_Ogg_videos_using_a_Java_applet)

And this info is for you:

```
<p id="player">Non existing media file - click to play</p>

<audio preload="none" controls>
    <source id="wav" src="http://yourpage.com/false.wav" />
    <source id="mp3" src="http://yourpage.com/false.mp3" />
</audio>
```

And with this you simple use js:

```
$("#player").on("click", function () {
    alert("Trying to play file.");
    try {
        $('audio')[0].play();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error playing file!");
    }
});
$("audio").on("error", function (eevent) {
        alert("Error at audio tag!");
    });
$("#wav").on("error", function (event) {
        alert("No wav file!");
    });
$("#mp3").on("error", function (event) {
        alert("No mp3 file!");
    });
```

Comment: Here I have found another similar sollution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614803/how-to-check-if-html5-audio-has-reached-different-errors

Comment: The problem is that the error is thrown at the moment of creation, not when I try to play the file... But maybe that other solution you posted could help, I'll give it a try.