# How to Greyed Out a Audio Player or Div if the audio file is corrupt

Tags: html, css, vue.js, audio-player

I am working on a vue.js project where I have created an audio player which gets the audio file URL from Backend(java). The audio file is hosted in was.
The problem is some audio files(mp3) are corrupted in this case the "spinner" for loading keeps on spinning. I want that if the file is corrupt the whole audio player should greyed out(disabled).

How to do this?

Or how to check if the audio is corrupt?

```
       <audio-player :audioFile="profile.audioFile" >
       </audio-player>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if HTML5 audio has reached different errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614803/how-to-check-if-html5-audio-has-reached-different-errors)

Comment: `audio-player` is a homemade component ? If it's the case, you could check somehow for the error and apply a block with some opacity on top of your player.

Comment: @MaieonBrix thanks for sharing. I think this what I wanted, let me try suggesting from the question. Thanks

Comment: @kissu yes the component is home made but I  am using the html5 <audio> tag only. That is exactly my question how to check the error and then grey out the player.